# specific text to random pics

Tags: xcode, xcode4.6

I have a random pic method in my application:

```
- (void)showimage
```

{
    int randomimages = arc4random() % 6;

```
switch (randomimages) {
    case 0:
        self.rahmen.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
        break;
    case 1:
        self.rahmen.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
        break; ...
```

But now I want to show a specific Text to each of the random Pics.
to random pic 3.png should come "Info for pic 3".
How can I do this? With an if option?
Something like: 
if shown picture == 4
label.text = @"information to pic 4"
else if ...
What would be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to take all those  stuff simply try like this,

```
    int randomimages = arc4random() % 6;//here you are getting the random number.

    self.rahmen.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png",randomimages]];
```

for displaying text you can take an array which contains all the titles and you can set the title based on this randomimages value.

```
label.text=[titlesArray objectAtIndex:randomimages];
```